# Add Metadata, headers (Expires, CacheControl) to a file uploaded to Alicloud OSS using the Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, object-storage

I am trying to find out how to add in Metadata or headers (Expires, CacheControl etc. I want to have global defaults with headers, this works in Laravel 5 and S3 Amazon, only change config/filesystems.php file like so:

```
's3' => [
   'driver' => 's3',
   'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
   'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
   'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
   'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
   'source' => env('S3_SOURCE'),
   'options' => ['CacheControl' => 'max-age=604800, public', 'Expires' => gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', strtotime('+7 day'))]
]

'oss' => [
   'driver' => 'oss',
   'key' => env('OSS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
   'secret' => env('OSS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET'),
   'endpoint' => env('OSS_ENDPOINT'),
   'bucket' => env('OSS_BUCKET'),
   'region' => env('OSS_REGION'),
   'source' => env('OSS_SOURCE')
   'options' => ['CacheControl' => 'max-age=604800, public', 'Expires' => gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', strtotime('+7 day'))]
]
```

and this code it's not work in Alicloud OSS(Object Storage Service)